# Is it always true that the React usestate setter is not reflecting a change immediately in any condition? What if the usestate is used in onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question about the useState hook. We all know that the useState setter method is not reflecting a change immediately. For example,

```js
const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
     <form onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setName("submit");
          console.log("onSubmit:",name)
        }} 
       className="form">
        <div>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">add </button>
      </form>
   </React.Fragment>
   );
};
  
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

When one inputs some words and clicks ADD, nothing presents after "onSubmit:" in the console. The reason is that the setter setName() is not reflecting a change immediately. However, if the setter method is implemented in the onChange property, the change can be applied immediately by setName(). For example, if we move setName() from **onSubmit** to **onChange** in the input element.

```js
const App = () => {
const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

return (
  <React.Fragment>
   <form onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("onSubmit:",name)
      }} 
     className="form">
      <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setName(e.target.value);
            }} 
          />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">add </button>
    </form>
 </React.Fragment>
 );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

console.log() is going to print out some words we input after "onSubmit:".  Is it true that setter method is going to be immediately applied in the onChange property? Or do I misunderstand some details about React useState setter method? I reviewed several qeustions about React useState setter from Stackoverflow. They seem not to be directly related to my problem.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> if the setter method is implemented in the onChange property, the change can be applied immediately by setName()

I am not sure what you mean by immediately here, but, no, in neither case is the change applied 'immediately'

the way the `setter` of `useState` works is, once the 'setting' is done, the component re-renders, and in this process the component becomes 'aware' of the newly set value.

So, in case number 1, where you `setName` in `onSubmit`, and immediately after, you `console.log`, well, the `console.log` fires before the component has re-rendered, and hence it is not 'aware' of the new value against `name`

in case number 2, everytime `onChange` fires, you are setting `name` -> which is re-rendering the component, and making `onSubmit` 'aware' of the new `name` value. So then, when you finally press the submit button and trigger `onSubmit`, it is already 'aware' of the latest `name` value, and `console.log`s it accordingly.

Hopefully that paints a picture for you on how state update works in react.

Comment: I've tried to insert console.log(name) right after setName(e.target.value). Whenever I type any letter in the input box, onChange fires and console.log is going to print out the latest value of `name'. Looks like the conclusion is: Definitely, onSubmit won't re-render. But the key point is that onChange is going to re-render once it triggers.   Thank you for your answer.